# Why Spark Cassandra connector allows filtering even when if query table by partitiong key using DataFrame API?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

Given Cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE data_storage.stack_overflow_test_table (
    id int,
    text_id text,
    clustering date,
    some_other text,
    PRIMARY KEY (( id, text_id ), clustering)
)
```

the following query is a valid query:

```
select * from data_storage.test_table_filtering where id=4 and text_id='2';
```

Since I included all columns from partitioning key to query.

Consider following code:

```
val ds = session.
  read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map("table" -> "stack_overflow_test_table", "keyspace" -> "data_storage"))
  .load()
  .where(col("id") === 4 &&
  col("text_id") === "2").show(10)
```

Since spark-cassandra connector pushes predicate to Cassandra, I expect query that Spark will send Cassandra be something like

```
SELECT "id", "text_id", "clustering", "some_other" FROM "data_storage"."stack_overflow_test_table" WHERE "id" = ? AND "text_id" = ?
```

However, I can see in logs

> 18/04/09 15:38:09 TRACE Connection: Connection[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042-2, inFlight=1, closed=false], stream 256, writing request PREPARE SELECT "id", "text_id", "clustering", "some_other" FROM "data_storage"."stack_overflow_test_table" WHERE "id" = ? AND "text_id" = ?   ALLOW FILTERING

**That means spark-cassandra-connector adds ALLOW FILTERING to query**

Therefore I have two questions:

1. Does this affecting performance?
2. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cassandra's connector documents that allow filtering is added implicitly. See [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md#filtering-rows---where). Note how it warns about not all predicates being OK with the actual database.

1. *"Does this affecting performance?"*

    The documentation says:

   > Note: Although the ALLOW FILTERING clause is implicitly added to the generated CQL query, not all predicates are currently allowed by the Cassandra engine. This limitation is going to be addressed in the future Cassandra releases. Currently, ALLOW FILTERING works well with columns indexed by clustering columns.

   I read this as performance wouldn't be affected as a result of the implicit `allow filtering`
2. *"Is there a workaround?"*

   Workaround for making the query faster or for preventing that `'allow filtering'` be sent? The simple answer is that there should be no need for a "workaround". Send a predicate that makes an efficient query for Cassandra, just as in your case, and the database engine will pick the best execution plan.

Comment: You absolutely right, if trace query via cqlsh, no change in query plan can be observed due to implicit `ALLOW FILTERING`